# Extending parent routing when extending bundles

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2 (2.0.3) I have a BetaBundle that is set as the parent of a AlphaBundle. Is it possible to override some routes while still keeping the parent originals routing definition ?

I have tried importing the parent routing.yml inside the child routing.yml file but it naturally result in a `circular reference` exception.

Is there any standard way to achieve this using yml and files named routing.yml in the same relative path ?

Comment: Is it a problem to copy the whole routing file to your child bundle and just overwrite the routes you want to override?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution. Actually, it's not that bad, but I would be really happy to see another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override your AlphaBundle anything that uses the @AlphaBundle shortcut will look in @BetaBundle first. The only way I've found to solve this kind of problem is to have the extending bundle (BetaBundle) quit using the @ shortcut, and include your AlphaBundle's route using it's path.

As an alternative you could try renaming your BetaBundle's route file so that it doesn't override AlphaBundle's file, and then configure your app/config/routing.yml to include your BetaBundle's renamed routing file.